# Loop a Video on Echo Show

Tags: node.js, loops, video, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building a skill for Echo Show and I've been trying to loop a video (mp4) file. I use the below code to play the video:

```
if (this.event.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces.VideoApp) {
    this.response.playVideo(LINK);
} else {
    this.response.speak("The video cannot be played on your device. " +
    "To watch this video, try launching the skill from your echo show device.");
}
```

Unfortunately, regardless of which looping function I use, I either run into a general Amazon error or it simply plays the video once.

I've seen another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421491/how-to-loop-audio-in-alexa?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) that kinda showed how to loop an audio file, but I haven't been able to apply similar logic to video.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is looping is not yet supported for VideoApp directive. You can use Video apl component to loop a video. https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-video.html

Comment: Hah, I completely forgot about this and ended up taking a different direction with my project. I assume your solution works, so I'll mark it as accepted, but I don't know if it's correct. If someone else could verify, it'd be great!

Comment: Yes, it works. I've been using APL to show and loop videos in my custom skill.